# How do I calculate the range of a F1-score from a confusion matrix of 3 class,A,B,C

Tags: machine-learning, confusion-matrix, mathematics

Is there any support function to calculate the average F1-score range?

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]


f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
```

From documentation

> Calculate metrics for each label, and find their average weighted by support (the number of true instances for each label). This alters ‘macro’ to account for label imbalance; it can result in an F-score that is not between precision and recall.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html

Answer (score 0):

One function from Scikit-learn that you can use is the `classification_report` ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)).

Here is an example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

y_true = ["A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "C"]
y_pred = ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "C", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C"]

report = classification_report(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred)
print(report)

>>               precision    recall  f1-score   support
>> 
>>            A       1.00      0.50      0.67         8
>>            B       0.60      0.75      0.67         4
>>            C       0.57      1.00      0.73         4
>> 
>>    micro avg       0.69      0.69      0.69        16
>>    macro avg       0.72      0.75      0.69        16
>> weighted avg       0.79      0.69      0.68        16
```

From this, you can extract the **F1-score per class**. This can be useful because you can see in more details where your model isn't performing well.

You can also see the **micro**, **macro** and **weighted** averages.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to **[this Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/getawork/bc7b33e9bda305effa54c140e5a8a59c)**.

For convenience I copy-pasted the code from the link here (comments ommited):

```
def get_f1_score(confusion_matrix, i):
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    TN = 0
    FN = 0

    for j in range(len(confusion_matrix)):
        if (i == j):
            TP += confusion_matrix[i, j]
            tmp = np.delete(confusion_matrix, i, 0)
            tmp = np.delete(tmp, j, 1)

            TN += np.sum(tmp)
        else:
            if (confusion_matrix[i, j] != 0):

                FN += confusion_matrix[i, j]
            if (confusion_matrix[j, i] != 0):

                FP += confusion_matrix[j, i]

    recall = TP / (FN + TP)
    precision = TP / (TP + FP)
    f1_score = 2 * 1/(1/recall + 1/precision)

    return f1_score
```

When you want to calculate F1 of the first class label, use it like: *`get_f1_score(confusion_matrix, 0)`* .

You can then average F1 of all classes to obtain Macro-F1.

By the way, **[this site](https://onlineconfusionmatrix.com)** calculates F1, Accuracy, and several measures from a 2X2 confusion matrix easy as pie.